# How do I display a gallery using all images in a specific folder without using PHP or SQL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I want to make it really simple.

I place in an image in the folder, then, it will automatically be added in the gallery as I hit refresh.

I'm not quite sure if this is possible in javascript/jquery.

edit: a plug-in would suffice neatly.

Comment: You can, you could use for example C# or java instead.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but it will generate an automatic HTML page. But it is a huge security risk. On your server, enable automatic indexes on that folder. As long as you don't have an `index.htm`, `index.html`, `index.php`, `default.asp` or any other index page, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is a new feature in html5 upcoming but it's not quiet well supported yet by browsers:

See this article:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

If you only want to show your page in InternetExplorer you can access the FileSystemObject

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

(A feature that was available in Firefox for this purpose was removed entirely since version 17 ..)

In general every way to access the file system via JavaScript out of the WebBrowser is illegal by definition (no matter if certain technologies give you the possibility somehow) because it's intended to run sandboxed. So don't expect to find a simple solution to that ...